# caching whole php output to static html using htaccess and modrewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching

I've a Php website which for some page already create a whole output cache file, though isn't saved as `.html` and on requests is still sent from Php, it miss the hosting cache for static files which have very good performances.

The cache files are saved in a directory based on their `md5(Url)`.

I wonder if with `mod_rewrite` would be possible to obtain a similar result but with html static files, I think I've seen something similar sometime ago with a WordPress cache plugin (but at the time I didn't paid much attention).

What can I use instead of `md5()` with `mod_rewrite` to transform the whole Url in a valid unique filename?

My Url are virtual routes and very simple: `/level1/level2/level3/` (is a work still in progress but I don't think to use more than 3 levels, `levelN` obviously is an example, can be any word)

To simplify what I'd like would be:

*mod_rewrite*: /cache/unique(Url).html exist? Load it

*php*: /cache/unique(Url).html doesn't exist? Create it

What I can use for `unique`?

Comment: Please elaborate on *which for some page already create a whole output cache file*.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary based on the Url/route I choose if a page is to be cached, the *cache file* is saved with a small payload (used then to check if it is expired). I didn't write the current cache system, I don't think that's relevant for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that, I am not going to provide the whole code just idea would be enough.

Let's start with **.htaccess**
Write you .htaccess in a way that it redirect every missing file to your directory index.
It could look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Now You will get Request to index.php if called page is is not found.

Rather than using using hashed file name , it is ok to use directory structure, which will be faster and more human readable.

You can create directories on the fly.

In **index.php**
Before pushing data back to browser make sure you get it all in a variable . You can do that with **include** functions. 
See Example 5 on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) .

Save the data based on you directory level.

```
$levels = explode('/',<REQUESTED_URI>);
$filename = array_pop($levels);
foreach($levels as $level)
   // Create Directory if does not exit
```

In the end , thats just basic idea , you have to figure out tweeks and tricks on your own.

Comment: thanks, I've no problems with the Php side, is the `.htaccess`/`mod_rewrite` syntax I don't know and for which I'd like details. While I can use directories and sub-directories I would prefer to keep everything in only one dir. A simple `mod_rewrite` *slash* to *dash* would do I think

Comment: Yes, there are lot of questions asked on SO regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

In the end is quite simple, though I had to use same directories and sub-directories of the Url, the WordPress plugin I was remembering is supercache and the `mod_rewrite` I'm using is almost the same.

Transforming Url with `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` is possible but not simple and with some limitation (but even to *md5* using `RewriteMap` and `prg` if you have access to the server configuration).

`.htaccess` if the static cache file exist, load it:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /cache/$1/index.html [L]
```

Php, I'm using CodeIgniter but should be easy to edit for Php only, perhaps using `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`:

```
private function cache_output() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $uri = uri_string(); /* expect something like: level1/level2 (no heading/trailing slash */ 
    $dir = FCPATH.'cache'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.str_replace('/',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$uri);
    $file = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'index.html';
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0755 & ~umask(), TRUE);
        }
        $output = $this->output->get_output();
        file_put_contents($file, $output);
        chmod($file, 0644 & ~umask());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used something like that years ago, and managed to find the source. My `.htaccess` settings looked like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^$ /cache/index.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /cache/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ ./index.php [L]
```

Which supports getting the start page by a different filename and also skipping cache on any POST-requests.

The PHP code to generate the file is pretty straight forward:

```php
ob_start();

// ... main page code & output

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$html = ob_get_clean();

$start = array('/', '', '/index.php');
$blacklisted = array('/some/url/exception', 'another/one');

if (in_array($url, $start, true)) {
    $path = './cache/';
    $file = 'index.html';
} else {
    $pos = strpos(strrev($url), '/');
    $pos = ($pos ? (strlen($url) - ($pos - 1)) : false);

    $path = './cache' . substr($url, 0, $pos, '/'));
    $file = substr(strrchr(rtrim($url, '/'), '/'), 1) . '.html';
}

if (!in_array($url, $blacklisted, true)) {
    $parts = explode('/', $path);

    foreach($parts as $part) {
        $dir = (isset($dir) ? $dir . $part . '/' : $part . '/' );

        if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            @mkdir($dir, 0777);
        }
    }

    file_put_contents($path . '/' . $file, $html);
}
```

For cache invalidation I manually called `@unlink('./cache/comment/id/'. $id . '.html');` on POST requests for editing content. Sometimes a `glob()` type recursive deletion for nested resource URLs.

For dynamic parts of the page, like the menu that differed for guests compared to logged in users I simply used some Javascript in combination with a cookie to determine which to show.

Pretty simple, but very effective.